# How to call function passDataToService () on success of socket response in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket

I want to call angular function. below find the code.

app.component.ts

```
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/rx';

mySocketFun() {
     if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2012/echo');
             ws.onopen = function() {
              ws.send("4001","billNo12",1000);
            };

           ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
               this.passDataToService(evt);
           }
    }
}

passDataToService(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

how to call passDataToService() when ws.onmessage is triggered.

Comment: ws.onmessage.then((evt) => {this.passDataToService(evt)})

Comment: @ajrthegreat thansk for answering

Comment: No worries, did it work?